# Quadratic First Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ (x^3+x^2+x+1)(dy/dx)^2 - (3x^2+2x+1)y(dy/dx) + 2xy^2=0 $

Can anyone tell me how to solve this equation? I cannot find any suitable substitution. I tried turning it into a linear equation but i am unable to solve the resulting integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The first order differential equation is separable. We have that

$$(x^3+x^2+x+1)= (x^2+1)(x+1)$$
$$-(3x^2+2x+1)y= −(x+1)(2xy)−(x^2+1)y$$

therefore the ODE can be factored into two linear differential equations

$$\Big(y - (x + 1) \frac{dy}{dx}\Big) \Big(2 xy- (x^2 + 1) \frac{dy}{dx}\Big) = 0$$

which means that you need to solve

$$y - (x + 1) \frac{dy}{dx}=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x+1} \tag{1}$$
$$2 xy- (x^2 + 1) \frac{dy}{dx}=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2+1} \tag{2}$$